# regular expression to extract two items from a long string

Tags: javascript, java, regex, linux

There are some strings having the following type of format,

```
{abc=1234457, cde=3,  label=3352-4e9a-9022-1067ca63} <chve>  abc?  123.456.789, http=appl.com
```

I would like to extract `1234457` and  `3352-4e9a-9022-1067ca63`, which correspond to `abc`  and `label` respectively.

This is the javascript I have been trying to use, but it does not work. I think the regular expression part is wrong.

```
var headerPattern = new RegExp("\{abc=([\d]*),,label=(.*)(.*)");
if (headerPattern.test(row)) {
   abc = headerPattern.exec(row)[0];
    label = headerPattern.exec(row)[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: `abc=(\d*).*?label=([^}]*)`

## Explanation

- `abc=` literal match
- `(\d*)` catch some numbers
- `.*?` Lazy match
- `label=` literal match
- `([^}]*)` catch all the things that aren't the closing brace

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with:

```
\{abc=(\d+).*label=(.+)\}.*
```

Your have two problems in `\{abc=([\d]*),,label=(.*)(.*)`:

- Using `abc=([\d]*),,`, you are looking for `abc=([\d]*)` followed by the **literal** `,,`. You should use `.*` instead. Since `.*` is nongreedy be default, it will not match past the `label`.
- By using `label=(.*)(.*)`, the first `.*` captures all the remaining text. You want to only catch text until the edge of the braces, so use `(.*)}.*`.

Disclaimer: Made with a Java-based regex tester. If anything in JavaScript regexes would invalidate this, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the following way:

```
var row = '{abc=1234457, cde=3,  label=3352-4e9a-9022-1067ca63} <chve>  abc?  123.456.789, http=appl.com';

var headerPatternResult = /{abc=([0-9]+),.*?label=([a-z0-9\-]+)}/.exec(row);

if (headerPatternResult !== null) {
    var abc = headerPatternResult[1];
    var label = headerPatternResult[2];

    console.log('abc: ' + abc);
    console.log('label: ' + label);
}
```